# Uniform Convergence and Improper Integration

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, uniform-convergence

> Let $g:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f_n:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}, n\ge 1$ be integrable functions over $[a,b]$ for any $0<a<b<\infty$. Also suppose that
>
> (1) $|f_n(x)| < g(x)$ for all $x>0$ and $n\ge 1$;
>
> (2) $f_n\to f$ uniformly over each compact interval contained in $(0,\infty)$;
>
> (3) $\int_0^{\infty}g(x)dx < \infty$.
>
> Show that
> $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\infty}f_n(x)dx = \int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx.
> $$

From (1) and (3) we get that each $\int_0^{\infty}f_n(x)dx$ and $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx$ converges. And from (2) it follows that
$$
\int_0^r f(x)dx = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^rf_n(x)dx,
$$
for all $r>0$. Taking $r\to\infty$,
$$
\lim_{r\to\infty}\int_0^r f(x)dx = \lim_{r\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^rf_n(x)dx,
$$
so the question is whether we can interchange the limits on the RHS of the last equation, but I don't know what to use here. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: You can weaken condition $(2)$ to pointwise convergence in all of $(0,\infty)$ actually. That does require some non-trivial effort however.

Answer (score 2):

The big hint that allows you to interchange the limits, is that $$\int_0^\infty g<\infty,$$
and $|f_n(x)|<g(x)$ for all $x>0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This allows us to conclude that for all $r>0$ sufficiently large
$$\left|\int_r^\infty f_n(x)\right|\leq\int_r^\infty|f_n(x)|\leq\int_r^\infty g.$$
So if $\epsilon>0$ we can choose $r$ so large that for all $n$ we have
$$\left|\int_r^\infty f\right|,\left|\int_r^\infty f_n\right|<\epsilon.$$
Then
$$\left|\int_0^\infty f-\int_0^\infty f_n\right|\leq \left|\int_0^rf-\int_0^rf_n\right|+2\epsilon.$$
So we can choose $n$ sufficiently large to get
$$\left|\int_0^\infty f-\int_0^\infty f_n\right|\leq 3\epsilon.$$
Thus
$$\lim_{r\to\infty}\int_0^rf=\lim_{r\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^rf_n.$$

Comment: Hi, how and why can we choose such an r in the second inequality? Can you please explain. Something to do with the fact that the tail of the improper integral goes to zero. Isn’t it?

Comment: @rhombicosicodecahedron We choose the $r$ such that $\int_r^\infty g<\epsilon.$ We can do this as $g$ is integrable on $(0,\infty)$, hence $\lim_{r\to\infty}\int_r^\infty g=0.$  Now immediately we get that 
$$\left|\int_r^\infty f_n\right|\leq \epsilon,$$
by the first inequality. However, as $|f_n(x)|\leq g(x)$ for all $x,$ we also get that $|f(x)|\leq g(x)$ by order limits, so the inequalities work for $f$ as well.